# Prevent TFS to checkin unchanged files

Tags: configuration, visual-studio-2013, checkin

It seems a common problem that VS sometimes checkout files that are unchanged. Lately those files could be included in a check-in if one doesn't capture that some files are unchanged.

Is there a policy or a mechanism that prevents check-ins with unchanged files?

Answer (score 0):

TFS doesn't actually checkin the unchanged files. They appear in Pending Changes but if you look at the history of the checkin afterwards, you'll see those files are not included. Don't worry about them!

Of course if the files *are* included in the checkin, then something must have changed inside those files. Maybe formatting, line endings, encoding. Do a diff using Beyond Compare or something to see what changed.

Comment: I don't think this is true during a merge, since I've checked in unchanged files before during a merge and they cluttered up the changeset. These files had the status of just `merge` as opposed to `merge, edit` or `merge, branch`. Checking the diff reveals no differences at all, yet they still show in the changeset.